# Can I make a YouTube Series about programs on the Ubuntu Software Center?

Tags: software-center, video, youtube

I would like to make a video series of me touring the software center, browsing programs, and introducing others to the Ubuntu Software Center and its programs. Can I do this? I am asking because I do not want to infringe on any copyright or something of that sort.

Comment: Because Ubuntu is open source, I'm sure you'll be alright promoting it.

Comment: @Joren: Ubuntu is free software, but is protected by [trademarks](http://www.canonical.com/intellectual-property-policy). This question is legitimate, and the answer is not obvious as it may seem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Please go ahead and do it!**

You would not be infringing on any copyright or trademark around Ubuntu. [Canonical policies](http://www.canonical.com/intellectual-property-policy) explain:

> You can use the Trademarks in discussion, commentary, criticism or parody, provided that you do not imply endorsement by Canonical.

Even if you were using proprietary software such as OS X or Windows to demonstrate the operating system's capabilities and express opinions about software, there would be no SWAT team coming to knock down your door. As long as you don't claim ownership of the symbols, names, logos, etc. used and created by Canonical.

Comment: There are restrictions of use of ubuntu trademarks, http://www.canonical.com/intellectual-property-policy

Comment: This is a dangerous thing to say there are plenty of legal disclaimers with strict rules on what you can and can't do with Canonical's Intellectual property.  I know the OP has good spirit in mind but saying their are no problems with this legally is dumb, http://www.ubuntu.com/legal http://www.canonical.com/intellectual-property-policy have lots of info and if in doubt contact Canonical.

Answer (score -1):

Since Ubuntu is an open source OS, I think sharing information of what you know to others would be good for Ubuntu, so in my opinion you should do it.